Saxon 11 Get Configuration Features by Name
Updating from SaxonPE 9/10 to SaxonPE 11, and have found that the byName(java.lang.String name) for net.sf.saxon.lib.Feature<T> has been removed, and I cannot find a function within the Saxon api with the same functionality.
I cant find the documentation/release notes on why its been removed/dropped from Saxon 10 to 11 and am trying to find an alternative in order to be able to get a feature to use in
public <T> void setConfigurationProperty(net. sf. saxon. lib. Feature<T> feature, T value ) using  the url/name such as using http://saxon.sf.net/feature/xsltVersion to get the Feature for  XSLT_VERSION (detailed here https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/Feature.html#XSLT_VERSION)
e.g. in Saxon 9 the following could be done and I want to replicate that in saxon11
    String name = "http://saxon.sf.net/feature/xsltVersion";
    String value = "3.0"

    Feature<T> feature= (Feature<T>)Feature.byName(name);
    T tvalue= (T)value;
    net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor.setConfigurationProperty(feature, tvalue);
  

I see I could use setConfigurationProperty​(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Object value) to skip this issue entirely, however it was deprecated in 9.9 so would prefer to avoid.

Is that just an example? XSLT version is 3.0 anyway, might be possible that Saxon PE/EE 11 also allow 4.0 for some selected XSLT 4.0 features. Anyway, I think the idea is that there are static fields like https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/Feature.html#XSLT_VERSION where you can just use them in your code without any need to use strings.

Thanks for the response! unfortunately not just a examples we have a product using the saxon processor which is either set via a config file which contains the string (and with saxon 9.9 could use the byName method to get the relevant Feature), or a java api where can indeed use the static fields  as you mention

The preferred approach is to use constants such as
Processor.setConfigurationProperty(Feature.XSLT_VERSION, "4.0")

Compared with use of string constants, this has the advantage of being (a) more efficient, and (b) type-safe.
You can still dive down to the underlying Configuration object and use string property names there.

Thanks for the response! Was hoping to pass in the property as the string value from a configuration file, alongside having our own java api where we will very much can and will use this preferred approach! The previous byName function was perfect for the reading in of the name string and being able to create the Feature off that but would we have to create our own function now to be able to get feature via name?
